# How to write these `convert` commands in Magick++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, image-manipulation, magick++

I've decided on using Magick++ for my application. I know which `convert` commands I want to use but I don't know how to translate them into Magick++ code.

My application should quantize the colors in a imported image using a fixed hardcoded palette, with optional dithering (F-D, Riemersma, Bayer, Halftone, Random). It then passes the output to some later code.

Here are the commands that give me the results I want. Each one is individual, which one "gets run" depends on user set flags.
Also, `palette.png` will be a Image object generated on run and is not actually read from file.
Also, again, `out.png` will not be exported to file and will be instead be another Image object passed onto later code.

```sh
convert in.png -dither FloydSteinberg -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -dither Riemersma -remap palette.png out.png

convert in.png -ordered-dither o2x2,2 -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -ordered-dither o2x2,3 -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -ordered-dither o2x2,4 -remap palette.png out.png
# etc.

convert in.png -ordered-dither o3x3,2 -remap palette.png out.png
# etc.

convert in.png -ordered-dither o4x4,2 -remap palette.png out.png
# etc.

convert in.png -ordered-dither o8x8,2 -remap palette.png out.png
# etc.

# etc. through all ordered dithers

convert in.png -random-threshold 0x100% -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -random-threshold 10x90% -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -random-threshold 25x75% -remap palette.png out.png
convert in.png -random-threshold 30x80% -remap palette.png out.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `-dither` operator, use `Magick::Image.quantizeDitherMethod()` method.

```cpp
Magick::Image img("in.png");
img.quantizeDitherMethod(Magick::FloydSteinbergDitherMethod);
```

For `-remap` operator, use `Magick::Image.map()` method.

```cpp
Magick::Image img("in.png");
// ...
Magick::Image remap("palette.png");
img.map(remap, true);
```

For `-ordered-dither` operator, use `Magick::Image.orderedDither()` method.

```cpp
Magick::Image img("in.png");
// ...
img.orderedDither("o3x3,2");
```

For `-random-threshold` operator, use `Magick::Image.randomThreshold()` method.

```cpp
Magick::Image img("in.png");
// ...
img.randomThreshold(0.3 * QuantumRange, 0.8 * QuantumRange);
```

Checkout [Image.h](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/Magick%2B%2B/lib/Magick%2B%2B/Image.h) header file, and other Magick++'s source code files for reference. I believe the [documentation / examples](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html) are slightly out of date, but the developer comments are clear.